# HTML elements are not perfectly aligned with the rest of the elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

Why Available Times table, Assessor Notes textbox and Booking Notes textbox are not perfectly aligned with the rest of the elements in Internet Explorer. My page looks perfectly aligned in Forefox though.

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .LightBoxHeadingCell
    {                   
        font-family: "Arial",Verdana,Arial,Geneva,sans-serif,"MS Sans Serif";
        font-style: normal; 
        font-weight: bold;          
        color: brown;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .LightBoxNormalCell
    {                   
        font-family: "Arial",Verdana,Arial,Geneva,sans-serif,"MS Sans Serif";
        font-style: normal;         
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }               
    .AvailableTimes
    {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width:155px;
    }   
</style>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id='AssessoronLightboxDiv' class='dhx_cal_ltext' style='height:500px;'>
<table width='630px' cellspacing='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Location : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'>
                <select name='AssessorsLocationDropDown' id='AssessorsLocationDropDown' onchange='AssessorsLocationDropDownOnChange();' style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'>
                    <option selected = '' value='Evaluators Office'>Evaluators Office</option>
                    <option value='Clinic'>Clinic</option>
                    <option value='N/A'>N/A</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' style='display:none;'>
                Event ID : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'>
                <input type='text' id='AssessorEventID' disabled style='display:none;width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='ReasonRow' style='display:none;'>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Reason : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'>
                <select style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' name='ReasonDropDown' id='ReasonDropDown'>
                    <option selected = '' value=''></option>
                    <option value='Personal Leave'>Personal Leave</option>
                    <option value='Sick'>Sick</option>
                    <option value='Stat Holiday'>Stat Holiday</option>
                    <option value='Training'>Training</option>
                    <option value='Vacation'>Vacation</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                &nbsp; 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='ReserveRow'>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Reserve Type : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'>
                <select style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='ReserveTypeDropDown' name='ReserveTypeDropDown'>
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option selected = '' value='Regular'>Regular</option>
                    <option value='All Call'>All Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Reserved For : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'>
                <select style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='ReservedForDropDown' name='ReservedForDropDown'>
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option selected = '' value='Any'>Any</option>
                    <option value='CAT Only'>CAT Only</option>
                    <option value='In-Person Only'>In-Person Only</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='DatesRow'>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' id='StartDateHeadingTD'>
                Start Date : 
            </td>
            <td id='AssessorsStartDateCalendarTD'>
                <input type='text' id='AssessorsStartDateCalendar' disabled style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'>
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' id='EndDateHeadingTD'>
                End Date : 
            </td>
            <td class='LightBoxNormalCell' id='AssessorsEndDateCalendarTD'>
                <input type='text' id='AssessorsEndDateCalendar' style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='AvailableTimesRow'>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table width='620px' cellspacing='5' style='height: 150px;margin-top: 5px;border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='AvailableTimesTable'>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan='4' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                                Available Times : 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;'>08:00 AM - 09:00 AM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:30 AM - 09:30 AM;'>08:30 AM - 09:30 AM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:00 AM - 10:00 AM;'>09:00 AM - 10:00 AM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:30 AM - 10:30 AM;'>09:30 AM - 10:30 AM 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='10:00 AM - 11:00 AM;'>10:00 AM - 11:00 AM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='10:30 AM - 11:30 AM;'>10:30 AM - 11:30 AM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='11:00 AM - 12:00 PM;'>11:00 AM - 12:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='11:30 AM - 12:30 PM;'>11:30 AM - 12:30 PM 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='12:00 PM - 01:00 PM;'>12:00 PM - 01:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='12:30 PM - 01:30 PM;'>12:30 PM - 01:30 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='01:00 PM - 02:00 PM;'>01:00 PM - 02:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='01:30 PM - 02:30 PM;'>01:30 PM - 02:30 PM 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='02:00 PM - 03:00 PM;'>02:00 PM - 03:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='02:30 PM - 03:30 PM;'>02:30 PM - 03:30 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='03:00 PM - 04:00 PM;'>03:00 PM - 04:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='03:30 PM - 04:30 PM;'>03:30 PM - 04:30 PM 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='04:00 PM - 05:00 PM;'>04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='04:30 PM - 05:30 PM;'>04:30 PM - 05:30 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='05:00 PM - 06:00 PM;'>05:00 PM - 06:00 PM 
                            </td>
                            <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:blue;'>
                                &nbsp; 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='AssessorNotesRow'>
            <td valign='top' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Assessor Notes : 
            </td>
            <td colspan='3'>
                <textarea name='AssessorNotes' style='border: solid 1px #CCC; width:465px; height:50px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='AssessorNotes'>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='AssessmentsDivRow' style='display:none;'>
            <td colspan='4' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                <span style='font-size:11px;'>Assessments :</span>
                <div id='AssessmentsGrid' style='margin-top:5px; width:615px; min-height:88px; max-height: 110px; overflow: auto;'>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='BookingNotesRow'>
            <td valign='top' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>
                Booking Notes : 
            </td>
            <td colspan='3'>
                <textarea name='BookingNotes' style='border: solid 1px #CCC; width:465px; height:50px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='BookingNotes'>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks aligned in IE10, which IE are you referring to specifically?

Comment: I am using IE10. I can't upload an image because I am a new user. My Page doesn't render perfect in IE.

Comment: [here's what I see](http://oi42.tinypic.com/a3026e.jpg) - Is this your intended look?

Comment: Yes you got it. This is exactly what I see in IE.

Comment: No. How can I show you an image in Firefox since it is perfect in it.

Comment: it looks the same way to me in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<tr id='AvailableTimesRow'>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table width='620px'
```

to

```
<tr id='AvailableTimesRow'>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <table width='100%'
```

Comment: <table width='100%' it even screws my page in Firefox.

Comment: it was just a thought :-)